# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RCTWebSockerManager.connect') -- React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've been following the [guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/embedded-app-ios.html#content) on how to integrate an existing app with react native.

I've taken some liberties on the IOS side of things per recommendation of our IOS guy. When my view loads, I get a red error screen with this [stack trace](https://puu.sh/jRgDg/b844f139b2.png).

(sorry, not enough reputation to post images. Text is included below. )

```
    2015-08-27 22:19:37.739 [error][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] 'Warning: Native component for "RCTImageView" does not exist'
    2015-08-27 22:19:37.851 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] 'Running application "SimpleApp" with appParams: {"rootTag":1,"initialProps":{}}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF'
    2015-08-27 22:19:37.856 [error][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] 'Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating \'RCTWebSocketManager.connect\')
     stack: 
      connectToSocketImpl  index.ios.bundle:14464
      WebSocketBase        index.ios.bundle:14587
      WebSocket            index.ios.bundle:14458
      setupDevtools        index.ios.bundle:46060
      renderApplication    index.ios.bundle:44403
      run                  index.ios.bundle:44295
      runApplication       index.ios.bundle:44323
      __callFunction       index.ios.bundle:5552
      <unknown>            index.ios.bundle:5488
      guard                index.ios.bundle:5441
      <unknown>            index.ios.bundle:5488
      <unknown>            index.ios.bundle:5485
      perform              index.ios.bundle:7033
      batchedUpdates       index.ios.bundle:16454
      batchedUpdates       index.ios.bundle:6336
      <unknown>            index.ios.bundle:5484
      guard                index.ios.bundle:5441
      processBatch         index.ios.bundle:5483
     URL: http://192.168.1.70:8081/index.ios.bundle
     line: 14464
     message: undefined is not an object (evaluating \'RCTWebSocketManager.connect\')'
```

Here is my Podfile:

```
    pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
    pod 'React'
    pod 'React/RCTText'
```

("URL:" was changed to that manually rather than local host but responds the same in the browser.)

When I run:

```
(JS_DIR=`pwd`/ReactComponent; cd Pods/React; npm run start -- --root $JS_DIR)
```

Everything runs fine with a log yielding:

```
[22:32:15] <START> fs crawl
[22:32:16] <END>   fs crawl (744ms)
[22:32:16] <START> Building in-memory fs
[22:32:16] <END>   Building in-memory fs (454ms)
[22:32:16] <START> Building in-memory fs
[22:32:17] <END>   Building in-memory fs (242ms)
[22:32:17] <START> Building Haste Map
[22:32:17] <START> Building (deprecated) Asset Map
[22:32:17] <END>   Building (deprecated) Asset Map (75ms)
[22:32:17] <END>   Building Haste Map (836ms)
```

Once I start up the project in the xcode ios-simulator I get the aforementioned stacktrace. I can include my objective c code if it would be helpful but I omitted to prevent clutter as it seems like an issue with the react dependencies.

Thanks! Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I figured it out. If you're having this issue, fixing my podfile to this worked. Delete your Pods/ directory and then run pod install again with the following podfile. Restart the dev server for good measure too.

`pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'React'
pod 'React', :subspecs => [
    'RCTText',
    'RCTImage',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTWebSocket'
]`

Answer (score 0):

Are you running latest XCode? 6.3+ is recommended.

See Requirements: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

I updated to Xcode 6.4 and it fixed the RCTWebSocketManager.connect errors I had when doing this tutorial for the first time: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html#content